# Node.js OpenStack Swift plugin connection error

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, openstack-swift

I used NodeJS and [Swift plugin](https://github.com/firejune/swift)
I get this error when trying to implement connection

`Can not connect to Swift! Error: write EPROTO 101057795:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:794`

Seems that it's trying to use https, but I can't see in options to disable and use standard http.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. This plugin **by default**  uses https connection. So to change it to http you can edit the first `requrie('https')` in librarie's `swift.js` file  into `requrie('http')` :

```
 var https = requrie('http')
```

Comment: Thanks @Serob_b, that worked fine for me. 
Seems author skipped that feature in configuration settings, I assume many users will face that problem.

Comment: Yes, it would be better to give users opportunity to choose between connection types. But it's in github, you can push your variant ;)